# Responsive/adaptive design; table to single item based on screen size

Tags: mobile, responsive-design, adaptive-design

I'm redesigning a survey answering application and I want it to work on desktop, tablet and smartphone. The desktop and tablet can use more or less the same interface, but the phone is another issue.

The large-screen app interface is more or less a table with a group of questions in the first column and the answers in the next columns. (Questions can have anything from 1 (bool) to 9 choices). But this design is not easily transferable to a smaller screen. So my thought was to show single questions when the screen width goes below a certain threshold.

All questions are pre-loaded, and all answers are pushed to server "on click". (Yes JS is a requirement to answer). I'm using CSS to transition between "pages"/"groups" of questions on the large-screen app. On the small-screen I want to do the same thing, only this time between single questions instead of groups of questions.

See my exquisite sketch:

[image]

Can I do this with "responsive/adaptive design" at all? Or should I just load two different views on the different screen sizes?

Comment: this is definitely an adaptive design as you will (most probably) produce different HTML based on the device. You could do it server-side or client-side.